# Getting a compilation error with Google Cloud BigTable

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/transport/http_util.go:481: f.fr.SetReuseFrames undefined (type *http2.Framer has no field or method SetReuseFrames)

It seems to be coming from golang.org/x/net/http2.

Wish I could take this up directly with Google, but this is not on Github.
Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: What versions of grpc and go itself are you using? SetReuseFrames exists in the latest version of Go: https://github.com/golang/net/blob/master/http2/frame.go#L406

Comment: Based on this I'm guessing you need 1.8 or later: https://github.com/golang/net/commit/bb807669a61aca6092d8137da1fab2150bb96ad7

Answer (score 2):

Just figured this out. I'm using Glide for package management and it has a cache. Apparently it doesn't handle non-semantically versioned packages very well so I was compiling with a very stale package.

Solution: Manually remove the package in the cache, delete my glide.lock, then glide install.

`rm -rf ~/.glide/cache/src/https-golang.org-x-net
cd project-root
rm -f glide.lock  # or you could manually remove all references to golang.org-x-net 
glide install`

I have put in a feature request with github.com/Masterminds/glide to perhaps use a timed expiry.